# Seeking a formula for a constant increase, slowing down constantly

Tags: calculus

I like to find a formula for giving a discount rate at volume purchases. The higher the volume, the less shall be the increase per item.

So, if the base rate of a product's item is 5 dollars, then low volume purchase, e.g. 3 items, shall remain close to 3 * 5 dollars. At higher numbers I want to discount more. For instance, at 10 I'd only charge maybe 4 dollars, and at 30 I'd charge 3 dollars per item. and so on, up to a limit of 1 dollar per item, maybe at 1000 items. So, basically, I want to keep charging for every item, but gradually less. I'm looking for a simple formula, so if my examples don't fit exactly, that's fine.

Ideally, the formula does not use the sum operator but only things one can write as one-liners in procedural programming languages such as C and JavaScript.

(I suspect the answer is pretty easy. It's just that I'm over 50 and haven't done advanced math for a long time. I've tried a little with the Grapher app in OS X, with ln and such, but didn't find the right function for this. I'm not even sure about the tag I used.)

Comment: There are many answers, but your question is missing a key parameter to make any choice -  "what is the minimum marginal price?". In reality if you are actually selling things, this is your cost - you can't sell it for less. In your example, it could be zero. I assume you never want to reach this limit, just keep getting closer?

Comment: I've added a limit, does that help? But I rather initially thought of a formula like this: Every time x doubles (or triples), the slope of the curve (or its derivation?) gets reduced by half. That would get me a price curve that even in infinity won't result in a constant, right? And that's what I had in mind.

Comment: Well, it still depends on the general shape you want, but an exponential decay is simplest `y = 1 + 4 * exp(-x / k)` for some positive `k`. You might want something more like an S-curve, though, as the simple exponential favours earlier discounts... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: Added answer, with illustration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two obvious candidates are some kind of exponential decay, or an S-Curve if you don’t want to favour early discounts - see the graphic below.

The formulae, based on your parameters, are

Exponential decay:
`y = 5 - 4 * exp(-ke * x)`  : (ke in the graph is 1 / 250)

S-Curve:
`y = 5 - 4 * exp(-ks * (x - x0))` : (ks in the graph is 1 / 100, x0 - the half-way point - is 500)

[image]